# Как правильно писать код, что бы не повторять одно и тоже?

Tags: java, алгоритм, наследование, методы

Делаю задачку которая выглядит как мини рпг игра примитивного уровня. У меня есть 3 класса со своим набором скиллов (скиллы очень плохо прописаны, но они есть). И есть **пока что** один соперник. Я не понимаю как прописать методы так, что бы мне не приходилось прописывать каждый вариант битвы для **каждого** класса с **каждым** противником (то есть, универсальность кода). Далее ниже будет понятно, что я имею ввиду.

Фрагмент кода:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BattleDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        String name;
        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Введите имя");
        name = cin.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Выберите класс героя\n1.Воин 2.Лучник 3.Маг");
        choice = cin.nextInt();

        Warrior warrior = new Warrior(name,100);
        Archer archer = new Archer(name,100);
        Mag mag = new Mag(name,100);
        Skeleton skeleton = new Skeleton("Скелет", 100);

        System.out.println("Битва началась\n");
        System.out.printf("Имя героя: %s ", warrior.getName());

        if (choice == 1) {
            while (warrior.getHealth() > 0 && skeleton.getHealth() > 0) {
                System.out.printf("HP героя: %s\n", warrior.getHealth());
                System.out.printf("HP врага: %s\n\n", skeleton.getHealth());
                warrior.skillList();
                System.out.println("\n");
                choice = cin.nextInt();

                if (choice == 5) {
                    warrior.skillDescription();
                } else if (choice == 1) {
                    warrior.attackEnemy(skeleton);
                    skeleton.attackHero(warrior);
                } else if (choice == 2) {
                    warrior.warriorShield(skeleton);
                    skeleton.attackHero(warrior);
                } else if (choice == 3) {
                    warrior.cleavingBlow(skeleton);
                    skeleton.attackHero(warrior);
                } else if (choice == 4) {
                    if (warrior.defend(skeleton)) {
                        System.out.println("---Враг промахнулся---");
                    } else {
                        skeleton.attackHero(warrior);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Неверный ввод");
                }
            }
            if (warrior.getHealth() <= 0 && (!skeleton.isAlive())) {
                System.out.println("Герой и враг оба погибли\nGAME OVER");
            } else if (skeleton.isAlive()) {
                warrior.death();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Враг повержен");
            }
```

Проблема в том, что этот кусок у меня только для *Warrior*. Далее у меня идет просто копипаста, но с *Archer* и *Mag*. А что если я буду добавлять новые классы ? Снова добавлять кусок ? А если вдруг я захочу добавить еще одного противника ? Снова прописывать каждый вариант ? Как можно оставить все в одном таком куске ? И я не совсем понимаю какой код именно важен в таком вопросе, но я скину весь код. Так что, простите, если так нельзя. Я еще не задавал вопросов с таким кол-вом кода.
Далее я прилагаю код классов.

*Абстрактный класс родитель для всех моих классов героя.*

```
public abstract class Hero {
    private final String name;
    private int health;

    public Hero(String name, int health) {
        this.name = name;
        this.health = health;
    }

    public void takeDamage(int damage) {
        health -= damage;
    }

    public abstract void attackEnemy(Enemy enemy);
    public abstract String skills(int skill);
    public abstract void skillList();
    public abstract void skillDescription();

    public void death() {
        if (health <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Герой погиб\nGAME OVER");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Герой все еще жив");
        }
    }

    public int random(int min, int max) {
        max -= min;
        return (int) (Math.random() * ++max) + min;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }
}
```

*Класс Воина. Кидаю только его, так как остальные идентичны и отличаются лишь разными скиллами.*

```
public class Warrior extends Hero {

    public Warrior(String name, int health) {
        super(name, health);
    }

    @Override
    public void attackEnemy(Enemy enemy) {
        attackTemplate(0);
        enemy.takeDamage(10);
    }

    @Override
    public String skills(int skill) {
        String[] skillsList = new String[5];
        skillsList[0] = "Атака";
        skillsList[1] = "Удар щитом";
        skillsList[2] = "Рассекающий удар";
        skillsList[3] = "Защита";
        skillsList[4] = "Подробнее";
        return skillsList[skill];
    }

    @Override
    public void skillDescription() {
        System.out.println("Атака - герой атакует врага обычной атакой.\n" +
                "Удар щитом - герой атакует врага щитом (20 урона).\n" +
                "Рассекающий удар - герой рассекает врага (15 урона).\n" +
                "Защита - герой становится в защитную позу и с шансом 50% может уклониться от атаки.\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void skillList() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + ".|" + skills(i-1) + "| ");
        }
    }

    public void warriorShield(Enemy enemy) {
        attackTemplate(1);
        enemy.takeDamage(20);
    }

    public void cleavingBlow(Enemy enemy) {
        attackTemplate(2);
        enemy.takeDamage(15);
    }

    public boolean defend(Enemy enemy) {
        attackTemplate(3);
        return random(1, 2) == 1;
    }

    public void attackTemplate(int numberOfTemplate) {
        String[] templateList = new String[4];
        templateList[0] = "---" + getName() + " атакует врага и наносит 10 урона---";
        templateList[1] = "---" + getName() + " ударяет щитом и наносит 20 урона---";
        templateList[2] = "---" + getName() + " рассекает врага и наносит 15 урона---";
        templateList[3] = "---" + getName() + " становится в защиту---";
        System.out.println(templateList[numberOfTemplate]);
    }
}
```

*Абстрактный родитель всех соперников.* Mortal не имеет важности, так как там только один метод isAlive

```
public abstract class Enemy implements Mortal {
    final private String name;
    private int health;

    public Enemy(String name, int health) {
        this.name = name;
        this.health = health;
    }

    public void takeDamage(int damage) {
        health -= damage;
    }

    public abstract void attackHero(Hero hero);
    public abstract void attackTemplate();
    public abstract void startBattleMessage();

    public void death() {
        System.out.println("Враг повержен\nGAME WIN");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAlive() {
        return health > 0;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    public void setHealth(int health) {
        this.health = health;
    }
}
```

*Ну и сам противник*

```
public class Skeleton extends Enemy {

    public Skeleton(String name, int health) {
        super(name, health);
    }

    public void attackHero(Hero hero) {
        attackTemplate();
        hero.takeDamage(10);
    }

    public void attackTemplate() {
        System.out.println("---" + getName() + " атакует героя---");
    }

    public void startBattleMessage() {
        System.out.println("---Вы отправились на кладбище и встретили скелета---\n---Битва началась!---");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну так наследование надо не просто так делать, а чтобы работать с классами в единообразной манере. Так что делайте битву Hero с Enemy один раз и потом плодите сколько угодно новых классов.

Comment: @user7860670 устроить битву Hero и Enemy, а дальше, в зависимости от выбора, вызывать наследников ?

Comment: Сделайте метод - битву, принимающий Hero и Enemy, но передавайте в него любые экземпляры классов наследников в зависимости от чего там надо.

Comment: @user7860670 я дико извиняюсь, но можно ли небольшой пример. Каким образом передавать любые ? Что то вроде `public void battle(Hero hero, Enemy enemy)?`

Comment: Ну да, ведь этому методу будет не важно, передан туда Warrior или там Archer - внутри используется только их базовый класс.

Comment: @user7860670 а внутри метода прописать битву ?

Comment: Ну конечно, зачем же еще его делать?

Comment: @user7860670 хорошо, сделаю. Завтра отчитаюсь. Спасибо за оперативность и терпение

Comment: @user7860670 все получилось. Я создал метод, который принимает Hero hero и Enemy enemy. Но немного по-другому вносил туда данные. Я создал 2 метода (выбор класса и выбор моба), которые возвращают Object. А его я уже и закидывал в параметры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Моя реализация такая(Спасибо [user7860670](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/272035/user7860670) за наводку). В методе Dungeons создал метод, который возвращает Object и, в зависимости от выбора, возвращал созданный объект.

```
public Object selectDungeon(int choice) {
        Object enemy;
        if (choice == 1) {
            enemy = new Skeleton("Скелет", 100);
            return enemy;
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            enemy = new Wolf("Волк", 100);
            return enemy;
        } else if (choice == 3) {
            enemy = new Slug("Слизень", 100);
            return enemy;
        }
        enemy = "Неверный ввод или локация недоступна";
        return enemy;
    }
```

Далее тоже самое с выбором персонажей.

```
public Object selectClass(int choice, String name) {
        String text = "Неверный ввод";
        Object hero;
        if (choice == 1) {
            hero = new Warrior(name, 100);
            return hero;
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            hero = new Archer(name, 100);
            return hero;
        } else if (choice == 3) {
            hero = new Mag(name, 100);
            return hero;
        }
        return text;
    }
```

Далее присвоил результаты двум объектным переменным.

```
hero = selectHeroClass.selectClass(choice, name);
enemy = dungeons.selectDungeon(choice);
```

Далее вызвал метод битвы и закинул туда параметры.

```
battleDemo.battleProcess((Hero) hero, (Enemy) enemy);
```

Comment: Только нужно чтоб `selectClass` возвращал тип `Hero`, а `selectDungeon` тип `Enemy`, чтоб не делать ручного преобразования. Если передали неправильный `choice`, то бросаем `Exception`.

Comment: @RomanKonoval а, ну да, логично, спасибо